# Android - Custom Class imports differently not sure why

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom class in Android, very simple which I call to download and start the share intent on files in my app which come from a specific URL

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;

public class DownloadAndShare
{
    Activity activity;
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String URL;

    public DownloadAndShare(Activity activity, Context context, String URL) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    public void startSharing()
    {
        //Start shareIntent for this file
        File fileWithinMyDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String[] fn = URL.split("/");
        String fileName = fn[fn.length-1];
        File storageFolder = new File(fileWithinMyDir.toString() + "/myappname");
        //If storage folder does not yet exists, create it
        if(!storageFolder.exists()){
            storageFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        final String PATH = fileWithinMyDir.toString() + "/myappname/" + fileName;
        //Check if file exists in internal storage
        File file = new File(PATH.replace(" ", ""));
        if (!file.exists()){
            //file does not exists, download to internal storage for use
            new executeDownloadAndShare().execute(PATH.replace(" ", ""), URL);
        } else {
            Intent shareIntent = Globals.getShareIntent(PATH.replace(" ", ""), false);
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using..."));
        }
    }

    private class executeDownloadAndShare extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

        String filePath;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.general_msg_please_wait));
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            filePath = params[0];
            try {
                Globals.DownloadFromUrl(params[0], params[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return AppConstants.STATUS_FAIL;
            }
            return AppConstants.STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent shareIntent = Globals.getShareIntent(filePath, false);
            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share using..."));
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I try to create an instance of it inside one of my files, it needs to have the full `com.myappname.android.MyCustomClass myCustomClass = new com.myappname.android.MyCustomClass();` In order files I have it as just `MyCustomClass myCustomClass = new MyCustomClass()` and it works fine, however in a few files it wants the entire path.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this occurs? Both files where I call this are both extending Fragment, and one works while the other needs the full path.  I thought maybe it was something with a private method where it should be public etc, but I can't find anything wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and uninstall app from device/emulator before starting it again?

Comment: @parohy - I did a clean project, yes but that did not seem to help.  I will try again.

Comment: @parohy - i cleaned project and restarted Android Studio and it worked.  Go figure.  Thanks!!!

Comment: In my experience, this happens when there are two classes with the same name so when using one of them you have to use name with package name. Check if that is your case as well.
Also, try deleting your import and prefixes on long-named declaration and then reimporting. Good luck

Comment: I don't see a package line in your code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean you project and uninstall app from device/emulator before starting it again. If that not help, restart Android Studio.